# Rails 5 - How to set multiple paths for a search bar

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails and was trying to create a search bar with a simple textfield, dropdown selection, and a search button. This is the view code:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag [products_path,vendors_path...], :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>
    <div class="ui action input" id="home-page-search-textbox-container">
      <!-- SEARCH TEXTBOX-->
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search],
          placeholder: 'Products, Manufacturers, Vendors...')
      %>
      <!-- SEARCH DROPDOWN SELECTION -->
      <%= select_tag :dropdown_selection,
          options_for_select(@dropdown_selections),
          {:class => "ui selection dropdown",}
      %>
      <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->
      <div>
        <%= button_tag("Search", :class => "ui button", :name => nil) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is that depending on what the user selected in the dropdown, direct the user to that specific page.

**Example**: If the user selected products when searching, I want the the user to be directed to the products page. If the user selected vendors when searching, then direct the user to the vendors page and so on. The form_tag accepts a single path and it would work for that view but since multiple views are involved with the search bar, how can I pass the path depending on the user's dropdown selection? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the dropdown, how do you diferentiate beween products and vendors, etc?

Comment: I can access the value the value selected by the user using the params object at runtime(params[:dropdown_selections]). Also, products and vendors are models. Not sure if that was what you were asking.

Comment: I meant if the value selected comes from a dropdown and you want to redirect to different path you need check which path corresponds to the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it just checking some params that you can send depending on the user selection, this way you don't have to add multiples routes, but, check in the controller the params and redirect depending on this value.

Maybe something like:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: 'get', id: 'search-form' do %>
  ...
```

If the user selects some value you can identify as vendor, then you redirect to vendor, products, etc:

```
def search
  # vendor redirection
  if params[:dropdown_selections] == ...
    redirect_to vendors_path
  else
    redirect_to another_path
  ...
```

---

With your answer I've came to a possible solution.

The form points to the created GET path, this is

```
get 'search', to: 'home#search'
```

Plus all the other routes where to redirect.

```
<%= form_tag 'search', method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag :dropdown_selection, options_for_select(['products', 'vendors', 'manufacturers', 'others']) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

In the options for select there are all the possible values the user can select, this will be the way to create the route where to redirect in the controller:

```
def search
  options           = ['products', 'vendors', 'manufacturers']
  selection         = params[:dropdown_selection]
  known_path        = options.any?(&selection.method(:==))
  route_to_redirect = known_path ? selection.to_sym : root_path
  redirect_to route_to_redirect
end
```

- `options` are the same used in the select tag.
- `selection` stores the value selected by the user.
- `known_path` checks if the value selected is any in the options array.
- `route` checks if the known_path variable is true, if so, then transforms the value selected to its representation as a symbol to use it as the route. If is isn't, then redirect to the root_path.
- `redirect_to` uses the created route to redirect.

Comment: I'll try to use your suggestion since its purely rails solution, I'll try to see if I can get it to work and will mark it as the answer after confirming it since it doesn't involve any js code. Thanks for you help!

Comment: hey @Sebastián Palma, I tried to implement as you suggested but i'm not having any success. This is my routes file:                                                 
  get   '/result/all',            to: 'static_pages#all_result_page'
  get   '/result/products',       to: 'products#index'
  get   '/result/manufacturers',  to: 'manufacturers#index'
  get   '/result/vendors',        to: 'vendors#index'                                                            added the search function but the page is not redirecting properly.

Comment: your answer was spot on for my question with only a slight change to the form. I was using a form_tag with only one path(<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>). Instead, I needed to use the url_for method to specify the controller and action for the form to use and in that controller(<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'search', :action => 'primary_search'), :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>). After that I was able to render pages based on the user's dropdown selection in my primary_search action in my search controller.

Comment: That's great, I tried to use the same names as in the routes, in order then just to use then as a symbol to create the route. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Sebastiàn, I'm new to rails and I was stuck on this problem for a while so I decided to solve it to with jquery. To help someone in the future, here's the steps I used.

Step 1: define all paths I want to redirect from the dropdown in my routes file.
Step 2: implement the functionality via jquery.

```
var searched_text;
  var main_search_selections;

  // 1 - get selection values on change first
  $('select').change(function() {
    main_search_selections = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  });

  // 2 - take user to a page based on their selection
  $('#home-page-search-button').click(function(){
    // if the dropdown selection is vendors when searching
    if(main_search_selections == "vendors") {
      // go to vendors result page
      window.location.href='/result/vendors';
    }
    // if the dropdown selection is products when searching
    else if (main_search_selections == "products") {
      // go to products result page
      window.location.href='/result/products';
    }
    // if the dropdown selection is manufacturers when searching
    else if (main_search_selections == "manufacturers") {
      // go to the manufacturers result page
      window.location.href='/result/manufacturers';
    }
    // else if the only selection left would be all
    else {
      // go to the all result page
      window.location.href='/result/all';
    }
  });
```

**Edit:**
The above solution only works for simply redirecting the user to the proper pages. I wasn't able to use the params[:search] in order to perform my search logic. Using @Sebastià's answer, I was able to solve my issue.

**Step-1: Updated the search Form:** used url_for(:controller => controller_name, :action => action_name)

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'search', :action => 'primary_search'), :method => 'get', id: "search-form" do %>
        <div class="ui action input" id="home-page-search-textbox-container">
          <!-- SEARCH TEXTBOX-->
          <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search],
              placeholder: 'Products, Manufacturers, Vendors...')
          %>
          <!-- SEARCH DROPDOWN SELECTION -->
          <%= select_tag :dropdown_selection,
              options_for_select(@dropdown_selections),
              {:class => "ui selection dropdown",}
          %>
          <!-- SEARCH BUTTON -->
          <div id="home-page-search-button">
            <%= button_tag("Search", :class => "ui button", :name => nil) %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

**Step-2: Created a search controller**

**Step-3: Created an action to handle all search logic**

```
    def primary_search
        @dropdown_selections   = ['All', 'Products', 'Manufacturers', 'Vendors']
        @product_categories    = Product.all.map { |p| p.category }.sort.uniq
        @product_manufacturers = Manufacturer.all.map {|m| m.name }.uniq
        @product_vendors       = Vendor.all.map {|v| v.name }.uniq

        if params[:search].present?
          if params[:dropdown_selection].to_s.downcase == 'all'
            @products = Product.search_all(params[:search])
            render "/static_pages/all_result_page"
          elsif params[:dropdown_selection].to_s.downcase == 'products'
            @products = Product.search_products(params[:search])
            render "products_result_page"
          elsif params[:dropdown_selection].to_s.downcase == 'manufacturers'
            @products = Product.search_manufacturers(params[:search])
            render "/manufacturers/manufacturers_result_page"
          elsif params[:dropdown_selection].to_s.downcase == 'vendors'
            @products = Product.search_vendors(params[:search])
            render "/vendors/vendors_result_page"
          end
        else
          @products = Product.all
          render "/static_pages/all_result_page"
        end
      end
end
```

**Step-4: create a route for the search controller**

```
get   '/search', to: 'search#primary_search'
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a possible Rails solution.